# How to create an IntelliJ IDEA run configuration which allows to instantiate an IMain

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, interpreter

What is the trick to be able to run the Scala interpreter in the IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE Debugger. For example:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.{JLineCompletion, IMain}
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings

object IntpTest extends App {
  val settings  = new Settings
  settings.Yrepldebug.tryToSetFromPropertyValue("true")
  settings.usejavacp.tryToSetFromPropertyValue("true")
  val intp      = new IMain(settings)
  intp.initializeSynchronous()           // elaborate way of heating the CPU
  assert(intp.isInitializeComplete)
  println("----READY TO GO----")
  // ... later stuff here ....
  intp.close()
}
```

if I create a run configuration for this and launch the debugger, the application seems to freeze for ever in the commented line, CPU spins at max, nothing happens.

---

**EDIT:** It seems to hang in class path resolution, probably producing some infinite loop?

```
"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at java.lang.String.hashCode(String.java:1493)
  at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.hash(ScalaRunTime.scala:210)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$HashUtils$class.elemHashCode(HashTable.scala:398)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.elemHashCode(HashMap.scala:39)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.findEntry(HashTable.scala:130)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.findEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.get(HashMap.scala:69)
  at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:111)
  at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.getDir(ZipArchive.scala:123)
  at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.iterator(ZipArchive.scala:136)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.foreach(AbstractFile.scala:91)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.traverse(ClassPath.scala:308)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$16$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:317)
  - locked <0x3c73> (a scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$16(ClassPath.scala:317)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:317)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:317)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:297)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:375)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:375)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:375)
  - locked <0x58fd> (a scala.tools.nsc.util.JavaClassPath)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:370)
  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:243)
  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:194)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1229)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.init(Mirrors.scala:240)
  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror$lzycompute(Global.scala:59)
  - locked <0x6db> (a scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anon$1)
  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:57)
  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:37)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.<init>(Definitions.scala:166)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$definitions$.<init>(Definitions.scala:20)
  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.definitions$lzycompute(SymbolTable.scala:13)
  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.definitions(SymbolTable.scala:13)
  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1290)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$IMain$$_initialize(IMain.scala:149)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.initializeSynchronous(IMain.scala:170)
  at de.sciss.scalainterpreter.CompletionTest$delayedInit$body.apply(CompletionTest.scala:13)
```

(Scala 2.10.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine when enabling "Use alternative JRE" in the run configuration:

[image]

Libraries still seem to be found on the class path, debugger doesn't hang anymore.